# Plotting multiple graphs on single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a graph for each letter in alphabet(testing w/ just 2). The data I return from plot_letter func is ('LETTER', [range of years], [ data values one per year]). My for loop at the end calls the func, retrieves the data and creates and individual plot for each. How would I go about putting all graphs on a single plot?

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

start = 1880
stop = 1999
years = range(start, stop+1)
alphabet=['A','C']#,'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

def plot_letter(i):
year_values = []
for year in years:
    filename = 'yob' + str(year) + '.txt'
    z = open(filename)      
    c = 0
    d = 0
    for line in z:
        y = line.strip().split(',')
        y.remove(y[1])
        c += int(y[1])
        if i in y[0]:
            d += int(y[1])
    year_values.append(float(d)/float(c))           
return i,years, year_values

for i in alphabet:
    data = zip(plot_letter(i)[1], plot_letter(i)[2])
    x_val = [x[0] for x in data]
    y_val = [x[1] for x in data]
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)  
    plt.show()
```

Comment: do you want multiple subplots or all the plots in the same axes?

Comment: Either way, both solutions can be found [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/swcarpentry/notebooks/blob/master/matplotlib.ipynb)  under `Plotting multiple sets of data together` and `Subplots`

Comment: I've looked over ipython but my issue remains. The for loop only lets me create one plot at a time. I want to make multiple graphs on the same plot not subplots

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```
for i in alphabet:
    data = zip(plot_letter(i)[1], plot_letter(i)[2])
    x_val = [x[0] for x in data]
    y_val = [x[1] for x in data]
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)  
    plt.show()
```

calls `show()` multiple times.

If you want one plot with multiple lines, just move it out of the loop:

```
for i in alphabet:
    data = zip(plot_letter(i)[1], plot_letter(i)[2])
    x_val = [x[0] for x in data]
    y_val = [x[1] for x in data]
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)  
plt.show()
```